# How do I get consistent ranging from Estimote iBeacons? They go silent for 20 seconds

Tags: ionic-framework, ibeacon, ibeacon-android, estimote, android-ibeacon

I am using Ionic 3 and the Ionic Native IBeacon plugin to interact Estimote beacons.

I am attempting to range 4 beacons.

My problem is, the ranging is inconsistent.

The beacons seem to be detected 5-6 times, and then the following 18-19 `didRangeBeaconsInRegion` events bring back no beacons.

How can I get consistent ranging from the beacons? Even if it was consistent every 3 or 5 seconds would be much better for my use-case.

Here is my setup:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import {
  IBeacon,
  IBeaconPluginResult,
  IBeaconDelegate,
  BeaconRegion
} from '@ionic-native/ibeacon';

import { DetectedBeaconModel } from '../models';

@Injectable()
export class DetectBeaconService {

  constructor(
    private ibeacon: IBeacon
  ) { }

  private beaconSubject: BehaviorSubject<DetectedBeaconModel[]> = new BehaviorSubject<DetectedBeaconModel[]>(new Array<DetectedBeaconModel>());

  public detectBeacons(): Observable<DetectedBeaconModel[]> {

    this.setupBeaconDetection();
    return this.beaconSubject.asObservable();

  }

  private setupBeaconDetection(): void {

    const delegate = this.buildDelegate();
    const beaconRegion = this.buildBeaconRegion();
    this.startRanging(beaconRegion);

  }

  private startRanging(beaconRegion: BeaconRegion): Promise<any> {
    return this.ibeacon.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(beaconRegion)
      .catch(error => console.error(error));
  }

  private buildDelegate(): Object {

    let delegate: IBeaconDelegate = this.ibeacon.Delegate();

    // Callback function fired when beacons are detected.
    delegate.didRangeBeaconsInRegion()
      .subscribe(
      result => this.didRangeBeaconsInRegion(result),
      error => console.error(error)
      );

    return delegate;
  }

  private buildBeaconRegion(): BeaconRegion {
    const identifier: string = 'ThisCannotBeNullButIDontKnowWhatItsUsedFor';
    const uuid: string = 'XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX';
    // Setting the major here for testing only,
    // set it back to undefined after testing.
    const major: number = undefined;
    // const major: number = 12345;
    return this.ibeacon.BeaconRegion(identifier, uuid, major, undefined, true);
  }

  private didRangeBeaconsInRegion(pluginResult: IBeaconPluginResult): void {

    console.log('did range');

    // Beacons are not always detected when
    // this event fires, so lets double check
    // to make sure we have some before adding
    // them to the BehaviorSubject.
    if (!pluginResult.beacons) return;

    console.log(`has beacons, count: ${pluginResult.beacons.length}`);
    console.error(pluginResult)
    const beacons: Array<DetectedBeaconModel> = new Array<DetectedBeaconModel>();

    pluginResult.beacons.forEach(beacon => {
      const beaconModel: DetectedBeaconModel = this.mapRangeToDetectedBeaconModel(beacon);
      console.error(beaconModel);

      beacons.push(beaconModel);
    });

    // Publish to the rest of the
    // application the newly ranged 
    // beacons.
    this.beaconSubject.next(beacons);

  }

  private mapRangeToDetectedBeaconModel(beacon: any): DetectedBeaconModel {
    return new DetectedBeaconModel(
      beacon.proximity,
      beacon.major,
      beacon.accuracy
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Are your beacons configured to transmit only once every 20 seconds?  If so, this would explain what you are seeing.

Comment: Nope, I have them at 100ms, at the highest power level. The batteries are low, so I'm replacing those today, but I wouldn't think that would cause this problem.

Comment: I would certainly try with replaced batteries.  If they are low enough, you may not get consistent transmissions.

Comment: Will do, my other thought is, maybe android only sends the actual scan for bluetooth every 30 seconds..

Comment: The ionic beacon plugin uses the following cordova plugin:  https://github.com/petermetz/cordova-plugin-ibeacon  This in turn uses the Android Beacon Library here http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/, for which I am the lead developer.  So I can say with confidence that the scanning on Android should happen every 1.1 second by default and give you detections every 1.1 seconds unless somebody has customized it otherwise.  You might also try detecting with an off-the shelf app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.radiusnetworks.locate&hl=en

Comment: Thanks, that is good to know. I'll keep you updated with what I find out. I suppose it could be bad beacons in that case? That is, if the batteries aren't the problem.

Comment: @davidgyoung I have replaced the batteries and tested with the Beacon Locator app. That app is consistently finding the beacons every second (or there abouts). I don't know if the issue is in the plugin, but it is looking that way. I'll try and dig into the cordova plugin.